# how to render data, from 1row List with Datatable widget

Tags: flutter, datatable

i make a app for study flutter.
Pushed button, Make a random number 0~9. and Count each number, Save 1row List.

```
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                ElevatedButton.icon(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow_rounded),
                  label: Text('Play'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      int maxNum = 10; // << can be Change.
                      int rNum = 0;
                      rNum = Random().nextInt(maxNum);

                      strShowString = rNum;
                      Screen_Anyword().listStringCount[rNum]++;

                    });
                  },
                ),

                // DataTable(     // << How can i coding here ??
                //     rows: Screen_Anyword().listStringCount
                //     columns:
                // )
              ],
            ),
```

i want to render like this

[image]

is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I did not test it but I think its should work.

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
  children: [
    ElevatedButton.icon(
      icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow_rounded),
      label: Text('Play'),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          int maxNum = 10; // << can be changed.
          int rNum = Random().nextInt(maxNum);

          strShowString = rNum;
          Screen_Anyword().listStringCount[rNum]++;
        });
      },
    ),
    DataTable(
      columns: [
        DataColumn(label: Text('Index')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Count')),
      ],
      rows: Screen_Anyword().listStringCount.map((data) {
        int index = Screen_Anyword().listStringCount.indexOf(data);
        return DataRow(
          cells: [
            DataCell(Text('$index')),
            DataCell(Text('$data')),
          ],
        );
      }).toList(),
    ),
  ],
),
```